# Removing the word 'Part' from ToC entry (documentclass book and titlesec

Tags: table-of-contents, parts

I have a document of class book, and I have several chapters and sections in this document. Additionally, I group several chapters under one part, so I call `\part` to do this. At the end of my document, I have the appendices, which I start with `\appendix`. There are several chapters, and I would like to do the same here: to group them into a 'part' called Appendices.

So I call `\part*{Appendices}`. However, in the ToC, this entry contains the word 'Part'. I would like to know **what I can do to remove that single word 'Part'** for that single entry.

Thank you,

Below is an example MWE

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openany]{book}



% *** FONTS AND TYPESETTING PACKAGES ***
%
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}



% *** PAGE FORMATTING PACKAGES ***
%
\usepackage{appendix}



%
%% Macros & Preambles
%
%% ToC/LoFT formatting
\titlecontents{part}                     % Section
[0pt]                                    % Left(-indent)
{\vspace{10pt}\filcenter\Large\bfseries} % Before contentslabel
{}                                       % Format for numbered entry
{\partname\ \thecontentslabel}           % Format for unnumbered entry
{}                                       % Filler page format
[\vspace{12pt}]                          % After
%%
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\partname}{Appendices}}%
}
\makeatother

\titlecontents{chapter}                  % Section
[0pt]                                    % Left(-indent)
{\vspace{6pt}}                           % Before contentslabel
{\bfseries\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel\ } % Format for numbered entry
{\rmfamily\thecontentslabel}             % Format for unnumbered entry
{\titlerule*{.}\contentspage}            % Filler page format
[\vspace{6pt}]                           % After
%%
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\chaptername}{\appendixname}}%
}
\makeatother

%% Page title-ing
\titleformat{\part}[block]%
{\filcenter\large\bfseries}%
{\partname\ \thepart:\ }%
{5pt}%
{\large}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}%
{\vspace*{-40pt} \centering \chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}%
{40pt}%
{\vspace*{-20pt} \centering \large}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{20pt}{20pt}

\titlespacing*{name=\chapter,numberless}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}
%%



\begin{document}

\frontmatter

%% TABLE OF CONTENTS
\cleardoublepage
{
\tableofcontents
}


\mainmatter

%% PART I
\newpage
\part{Part}


% Chapter II
\newpage
\chapter{Chapter}
{
    \section{Section 1}
    Test

    \section{Section 2}
    Test
}


%% APPENDIX
\appendix
\newpage
\part*{Appendices}


% Appendix A

\newpage
\chapter{Appendix}
{
    Test
}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Try using the `appendix` package after reading the documentation (`> texdoc appendix`).

Comment: My bad, I didn't need to `\begin{appendices}` at all. I've corrected the MWE.

Comment: I did find out that if I called `\renewcommand{\partname}{}` before `\tableofcontents` this will remove Part from all ToC entries at that level. I did some reading and found out that `\contentsline` is called to effectively write the ToC entries. For the entry in which I'm interested, `\contentsline`'s first argument is `part`, so I'm assuming it's running some low-level code behind to append the correct `\partname`.